# C++ development in Eclipse, cannot find compiler

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I downloaded c++ tools to Eclipse (kepler) from:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler

the usual way -> Help -> Install new software -> etc

I just realised it does not contains any compiler so i downloaded MinGW and installed it too.

My eclipse still remains unknow how to compile and run c++ projects.

Here is the pic please tell me how to configure compiler paths or something like that.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly question, is g++ actually in `C:\MinGW\bin`? Have you tried just adding `C:\MinGW\bin` directly to PATH instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea would be to find where g++ was installed then add its directory to your PATH.

Comment: Well what is that? I thought MinGW is a c++ compiler, why do i need g++ (a compiler) too ? And where can i find that? Is it installed with MinGW ?

Comment: g++ is the GNU C++ compiler that MinGW ships. It is the C++ compiler. Check in C:\MinGW\bin.